# Where does this naive proof of the axiom of choice from the partition principle fall down?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Reflecting upon the axiom of choice and its independence from Zermelo Frankel set theory, I came to the conclusion that there must be definitions of sets in $ZF$ which encode the elements of sets, without providing the opportunity to encode some arbitrary order on the elements within the sets.

Part of the fundamental essence of sets is **all mutually distinct** elements - in fact for any $a,b\in X$ we have that $a\neq b$.  Question: Assuming the above insight is correct, is something slightly weaker than an ordering of elements possible, without the axiom of choice, namely to assign a distinct ordinal to every pair $a\neq b$ at the point we define the set?  It seems intutive to me that we must necessarily encode every pair of elements to be different, and therefore these $\neq$ relations might be ordered at the point they are encoded, for any expressible set.  Is that correct?

I was reading some material and it stated that it is an open problem whether $(A$ surjects $B\implies B$ injects $A)$ implies the axiom of choice.  The axiom of choice is equivalent to the statement that an injection $f$ can be found for every surjection $g$ such that $gf=\textrm {id}$.

If what I state in the second paragraph is possible, then it would seem that for any surjection, by picking the least-numbered $\neq$ we can at least get as close to defining the injection $f$ that gives $gf=\textrm {id}$ as identifying some pair $b\mapsto\{a_1,a_2\}$ simply by picking the pair $a_1,a_2$ having the least $\neq$-index.

Then if we define $A \cup B$, by the hypothesis of the 2nd paragraph, we would have assigned $a_1\neq b$ and $a_2\neq b$ distinct ordinals by which the least $a,b:a\in\{a_1,a_2\}$ can be picked (and therefore the injection $f$ can be defined), giving us the axiom of choice.

I assume I'm being naive in the second paragraph's assumptions, and may also have made more errors.  Assuming this does fail, where and why does it?

Comment: Actually, we often write “for all $i,j\in I$“ and include the case $i=j.$ The only case where $i\neq j$ is when we explicitly say $i\neq j.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews but that can never give us $|\{i,j\}|=2$, when $i=j$, right? Do I claim more than I write in this comment, in the question? Is this subtlety you're pointing out at the heart of the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a set $A$, and you assume that you can match a unique ordinal to each pair $\{a,b\}$ where $a\neq b$, then you can well-order $A$:

1. If $A=\varnothing$, we're done.
2. Assume it's not empty. Pick some $a\in A$, if $A=\{a\}$, it's well-ordered.
3. Assume it's not $\{a\}$, then map $b$ to the unique ordinal $\alpha$ matched to $\{a,b\}$ for all $b\neq a$. Now map $a$ to the least ordinal not used by that map.

So in order to do that, you actually assume that all sets are well-orderable, so you are assuming choice. The key point here is that you can't always "define a set" and even if you can define the set you can't necessarily define its elements. You're really thinking about *ordinal definable* sets, which makes a class that is well-orderable, so the argument you have in mind works there.